# input a list to html by python

Tags: python, html, list

I have a list of nine numbers and I want to put them into a html, such as aList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. So in python I want to type something like this myPage.write("aList[0],aList[1],aList[2],blablabla") Obviously it doesn't work...
So could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like:

**Note**: this has not been tested.

```
def listToHTML(list):
    str = "<ul>"
    for elem in list:
        str += "<li>" + str(elem) + "</li>"
    str += "</ul>"
    return str
```